# Getting the previous sibling of an element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page where i have multiple textboxes followed by a "browse" link, like this:

[textbox1] Browse
[textbox2] Browse
[textbox3] Browse

Now I want to know which textbox's browse link I pushed. I want to set a global variable (how to do that in Javascript/JQuery?) and save the textbox, or at least the class/id/name of the textbox so that I know which textbox to manipulate from the browse routing.

I don't know the id or anything of the textbox since this is generated at run time.  All I know is that it's the previous sibling to the browse link.

**EDIT:**
Cant get it to work, this is my jquery method, just for testing it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#BrowseLink').click(function() {
        alert($(this).prev('input[type=text]').attr('id'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

it makes an alert saying "undefined"...

This is my markup on the page:

```
<input id="Image"  name="Image" width="5px" type="text" value=""></input>&nbsp;<a id="BrowseLink" href="#">Browse</a>
```

**EDIT EDIT**
Looking at my markup i solved it, the nbsp; is an entity aswell, hence the need for `prev().prev()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// attach a click handler to all of the browse links
$('a.someClassThatAllBrowseLinksAreMarkedWith').click(function() {
    var associatedTextBoxValue = $(this).prev('input[type=text]').val();
    // TODO: do something with the value
    return false;
});
```

Comment: prev only ever gets the previous sibling.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [.prevAll()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prevAll#expr) method:

```
someGlobal = $(this).prevAll('input[type=text]:last').attr('id');
```

To make a global variable, just don't use `var` when you "declare" / initialise it.